# Get additional attributes when returning members of a group

Tags: java, ldap

Currently, I can get back a list of users from an Active Directory group but I would like to return more than just their CN/name. How would I do this?

For example, I have an AD group with 20 members. I can get their names but I would also like to return their job title in the output as well.

Comment: Please add some code and mention the API you are using for LDAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you can get their DNs from the group. To get any other attribute, you need to do an additional query (getAttributes) for each member.

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction and I've got it working now.